# how to load m4a file in python

Tags: python, audio, m4a

Is there an easy way to load m4a sound file in python. I've came across audiotools lib but I'm getting an error while using `to_pcm` fn

```
audiotools.open('file.m4a').to_pcm()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-e12405d92ce3> in <module>()
----> 1 audiotools.open(p).to_pcm()

/path/to/m4a.py in to_pcm(self)
    456             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    457             stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL if hasattr(subprocess, "DEVNULL") else
--> 458             open(os.devnull, "wb"))
    459         return PCMFileReader(sub.stdout,
    460                              sample_rate=self.sample_rate(),

/path/to/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo,    creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors)
    705                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    706                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 707                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    708         except:
    709             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

/path/to/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite,    c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session)
   1331                             else:
   1332                                 err_msg += ': ' + repr(orig_executable)
-> 1333                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
   1334                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)
   1335 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'faad'
```

Comment: The error you get points to invalid file path. Can you double-check? Preferably verify with absolute path.

Comment: I checked that, still getting the same error. This file I think it is coming from the audiotools lib itself which is need as a dependency or something like that, don't have any file with that name!

Comment: Also it will be great if there is something else other than audiotools to load m4a audio files.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's how you would do it using the [pydub](http://pydub.com/) library:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
audio = AudioSegment.from_file('file.m4a')
```

Answer (score 0):

The optional simple solution to load an audio file and play with it in python is to convert xxx.m4a file to xxx.mp3 first.

Then use the code here to load and play the audio:

`!pip install playsound`
`from playsound import playsound`
`playsound('xxx.mp3')`

Hope it works for you.